# shifting graph to the right and left when you must define each transformation in terms of y1

Tags: graphing-functions

I am having trouble shifting graphs when you need to define a function as y1= then you need to subtract or add to move it right or left.
Lets say you have

```
y1=√(1-x^2)
```

how do you then shift that to the right and left?
When you do

```
y2=y1-2
```

that shifts it up two.
How would you shift this over two?
you need to define y2 in terms of y1

Comment: The graph of $y = f(x - h) + v$ is the graph of $y = f(x)$ shifted to the right by $h$ units (so if $h$ is negative, it has been shifted to the left by $|h|$ units), and shifted up by $v$ units (so if $v$ is negative, it has been shifted down by $|v|$ units).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $y_1$ and $y_2$ are functions; so we can also work with its input.

In order to shift the graph horizontally, say two to the right, we need the value of the original function, $y_1(x)$, to be the same as the value of the new function two to the right, $y_2(x + 2)$. In other words, we want
$$
y_2(x + 2) = y_1(x)
$$
So a simple substitution gives
$$
y_2(x) = y_1(x - 2)
$$
For your example in particular, we have $y_2(x) = y_1(x - 2) = \sqrt{1 - (x - 2)^2}$. You can easily generalize this to arbitrary horizontal shifts to the left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function $y=f(x)$. If you intend to move the graph by $a$ units towards the right graph the function $y=f(x-a)$. Notice that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is any point on the previous graph ($y=f(x)$), then $(x_0+a,y_0)$ is a point on the new graph ($y=f(x-a)$).